# how to Remove user from microsoft team using graph API by id

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft graph API to Create and add members to  Microsoft Teams
but when i use API that remove a user from team it needs membership-id of a user in the team which i cant get easily
**<DELETE /teams/{team-id}/members/{membership-id}>**

is there a way to remove user from team using just user id, or an easy way to get the membership-id .
note: I don't want to use my DB to save data like the membership id.

Comment: Use `GET /teams/{team-id}/members/` to get the members in the Team and get the Id from there?

Comment: so what **do** you store as a user-id in your database if it is not the user-id ?
(e-mail and UPN can and will change over time)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to get the user, and then save that to a dictionary or simply pass the json data to a var for reference.

```
GET base_url/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

You'll get back:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
"id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
"businessPhones": [
    "+1 412 555 0109"
],
"displayName": "Megan Bowen",
"givenName": "Megan",
"jobTitle": "Auditor",
"mail": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
"mobilePhone": null,
"officeLocation": "12/1110",
"preferredLanguage": "en-US",
"surname": "Bowen",
"userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Then we can get the data

```
j = req.json
id = j['id']
```

Now just pass that id into the remove like you posted.

```
DELETE "/teams/{team-id}/members/" + id
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives error that the id is not valid, not sure what id they are referring to? (I used the Id provided from the response)

Comment: hard to say without seeing your code/response, but this is how you would do this. You can follow up with the documentation for graph.